# Add watermark to images

Tags: python, performance, image, opencv

Recently, I started reading image processing via opencv library in python.

I create a minio object storage and upload some photos into it. After that, I wrote a program which reads every image in each bucket in minio and watermark it with a simple logo. I read each image with `imread` and finally (after inserting a watermark), save it with `imwrite` (on the same image).

But when testing my code, I saw that for each image it took about 0.4 seconds. Since I want to do this simple operation for a lot of images, this time is not acceptable.

Here is a part of my simple code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


logo_img = cv2.imread('logo.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

scl = 50
w = int(logo_img.shape[1] * scl / 100)
h = int(logo_img.shape[0] * scl / 100)
dim = (w, h)
logo = cv2.resize(logo_img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
logo_height, logo_width = logo.shape[:2]


def watermark_image(image_name):
    image = cv2.imread(image_name)
    image_height, image_width = image.shape[:2]
    image = np.dstack([image, np.ones((image_height, image_width), dtype="uint8") * 255])
    # Blend
    ovr = np.zeros((image_height, image_width, 4), dtype="uint8")

    x_pos = int(random() * (image_height - 10 - logo_width))
    y_pos = int(random() * (image_width - 10 - logo_height))

    ovr[x_pos:x_pos + logo_height, y_pos:y_pos + logo_width] = logo
    image = cv2.addWeighted(ovr, 0.6, image, 1.0, 0, image)
    cv2.imwrite(image_name, image)


import time
start = time.time()
for bucket in buckets:
    objects = minioClient.list_objects(bucket.name, prefix=None, recursive=True)
    for current_object in objects:
        watermark_image('./test/' + current_object.object_name)

end = time.time()

print(end - start)
```

How can I improve my code and optimize it in order to need less runtime?

Suppose that I have a object storage which contains a lot of image. Actually I want to prepare an API, for people to request a watermark for every image and then I want to show them requested image after watermarking it online.

Comment: did you check whether most time was spent in the downloading/uploading, or the watermarking?

Comment: @maartenFabre most of time is for watermarking. i test it again and just for calling watermark, it is spent about 0.4 second, as seen before.

Comment: How large are the images you are using to test this?

Answer (score 2):

I'll focus more on the

> How can I improve my code

part of your question.

### Imports at the top

Move your `import time` to the top of the file, which is standard in Python.

### Code in functions

Your logo dimension calculation should be in a function instead of global scope. The code at the bottom should be in a top-level `main` function.

### Integer division

```
w = int(logo_img.shape[1] * scl / 100)
```

can be

```
w = logo_img.shape[1] * scl // 100
```

### Use pathlib

...so that this:

```
'./test/' + current_object.object_name
```

can be

```
Path('test') / current_object.object_name
```

Comment: thank you but my means was improve duration time not style code.

Comment: @cutename, by asking on Code Review, you should expect reviewers to assess *any and all aspects of your code* - askers don't get to constrain reviewers like that.